# Show that the open rectangle $(a_1, b_1)×(a_2, b_2)$ is not compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to standard metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Question:

> Show that the open rectangle $(a_1, b_1)×(a_2, b_2)$ is not compact in
> $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the standard Euclidean metric by finding an open covering
> that has no finite subcovering.

How to go about constructing this open covering that has no finite subcovering? What would be an example?

Additionally, why can't I argue directly that a set is compact $\Leftrightarrow$ it is closed and bounded, and since the open rectangle is not closed, it is not compact?

Comment: Write the rectangle as the union of nested rectangles $(a_1-{1 \over n} , b_1-{1 \over n} ) \times (a_2-{1 \over n} , b_2-{1 \over n} )$.

Comment: Whether you can or can't use Heine-Borel theorem depends on whether you just want to prove the claim or you want to answer the actual question, which explicitly wants the proof using open covers. Here is another approach. If the open rectangle were compact, then the open interval $(a_1,b_1)$ would also be compact because continuous image of compact set is compact. Can you show that $(a_1,b_1)$ is not compact by finding open cover with no finite subcover? To help you with that, think of how you could prove $(a_1,b_1)$ is not closed: by finding a convergent sequence in it that converges outside.

Comment: Finally, if $\{U_n\}_n$ covers $(a_1,b_1)$, can you use that to cover $(a_1,b_1)\times (a_2,b_2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely argue directly by using the Heine-Borel theorem (since it is not closed, it cannot be compact). It’s just that the problem asks you to argue by showing directly it does not fulfill the definition of compact.

An example of an open cover which doesn’t have a finite subcover is the collection $\{U_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$, where $$U_n = (a_1+1/n,b_1)\times(a_2,b_2).$$
Clearly, $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+} U_n=(a_1,b_1)\times(a_2,b_2)$. On the other hand, observe that $U_n\subset U_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Therefore, for any finite subcover $\{U_{n_1},\ldots,U_{n_r}\}$, consider $m=\max\{n_1,\ldots,n_r\}$. We have that $\bigcup_{k=1}^{r} U_{n_k} = U_m\subsetneq (a_1,b_1)\times(a_2,b_2)$.

Comment: Don't you want the minus sign instead of plus?

Comment: @Ennar No. If I had a minus, $\{U_1\}$ would be a cover (indeed, $U_n\supset(a_1,b_1)\times(a_2,b_2)$ for all $n$).

Comment: You are right, for some reason I thought $a_1+1/n < a_1$, silly.

Comment: @Ennar Happens sometimes :)